# Rendering Text after Scaling and Rotating UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

**Problem**

After scaling and rotating a UITextView using gestures, the text is sometimes fuzzy because the transformations are applied to the rasterized bitmap.

**Proposed Solution**

Once the gesture is complete, I need to return the transform to the identity transform, resize the frame based on the scale, resize the font based on the scale, and then re-apply the rotation transform.

**Implementation Attempts**

```
// Store original center before making changes

CGPoint originalCenter = textView.center;

// Restore transform to identity (frame property is invalid while transform is not identity)

[textView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];


// Attempt 1 - sizeThatFits /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Scale font

[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:textView.font.fontName size:textView.font.pointSize*scale]]; // scale refers to the scale of the pinch gesture that just ended

// Set frame to sizeThatFits

CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:maxSize]; // maxSize begins with the view frame size and is scaled at the end of each pinch gesture
[textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];

// Restore Center

[textView setCenter:originalCenter];

// Re-apply rotation

[textView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)]; // refers to the total rotation from all rotation gestures


// Attempt 2 - manually scale /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Scale font

[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:textView.font.fontName size:textView.font.pointSize*scale]];

// Scale frame

[textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textView.frame.size.width*scale, textView.frame.size.height*scale)];

// Restore Center

[textView setCenter:originalCenter];

// Re-apply rotation

[textView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)];
```

**Notes**

Everything I try *almost* works. In some cases, especially after multiple gestures (compounding the error), the text doesn't fit exactly right and will cause line breaks where there were none before.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Anyone who found the solution for this problem?

Comment: Old question, but wanted to give an update. I ended up abandoning the feature, but not before making some progress. The issue was that UITextView has a lot of complicated things going on in the layout. It's not just a box with text in it. So when you increase the frame size, the size of the text container does not scale by exactly the same factor. By learning more about UITextView layouts I'm sure it can be done. Best of luck